# How to transpose pyspark dataframe which has multiple index columns?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Company_Id | value | Approve or Reject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 3412asd | value-1 | Approve |
| 2B | 2345tyu | value-2 | Approve |
| 3C | 9800bvd | value-3 | Approve |
| 2B | 2345tyu | value-1 | Approve |

Note that ID can repeat with different 'value'. ID, Company_ID are indices.

Now I need the output to be:

| ID | Company_Id | value-1 | value-2 | value-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1A | 3412asd | Approve | NULL | NULL |
| 2B | 2345tyu | Approve | Approve | NULL |
| 3C | 9800bvd | NULL | NULL | Approve |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyspark pivot

```
df.groupBy('ID',    'Company_Id').pivot('value').agg(first('Approve or Reject')).show()
```